# How do I sort a WP_USER_QUERY by multiple meta fields?

Tags: user-meta, wp-user-query

I've got the following WP_USER_QUERY in WordPress:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'=>'meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array (
        0 => array(
                    'key' => 'last_name',
                    'value' => 'smith'
                    ),
        1 => array(
                    'key' => 'first_name' 
                    )
        ),

        );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

It's working in as much as it's returning the records I'm expecting it to, but the `orderby` is off - it's only sorting by their last name, and ignoring the first. How do I search by multiple custom user meta fields in this sort of query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. I had to write a custom query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 'orderby' parameter. Parameter description:

> Field(s) to sort the retrieved users by. May be a single value, an
>   array of values, or a multi-dimensional array with fields as keys and
>   orders ('ASC' or 'DESC') as values. Accepted values are 'ID',
>   'display_name' (or 'name'), 'include', 'user_login' (or 'login'),
>   'login__in', 'user_nicename' (or 'nicename'), 'nicename__in',
>   'user_email (or 'email'), 'user_url' (or 'url'), 'user_registered' (or
>   'registered'), 'post_count', 'meta_value', 'meta_value_num', the value
>   of `$meta_key`, **or an array key of `$meta_query`**. To use
>   'meta_value' or 'meta_value_num', `$meta_key` must be also be defined.
>   Default 'user_login'.

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => array(
        'user_rate' => 'DESC',
        'user_cat' => 'DESC',
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'user_rate' => array(
            'key' => 'user_rate',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'user_cat' => array(
            'key' => 'user_cat',
            'value' => $_GET['cat']
        )
    )
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```